# Misunderstanding of some parts of an example in Spark MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I follow this [example](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html) to create a simple personalized demo recommender using Spark MLLib.

I slightly misunderstand the meaning of `_._2.user` and `_._2.product` in these lines of code:

```
val numUsers = ratings.map(_._2.user).distinct.count
val numMovies = ratings.map(_._2.product).distinct.count
```

What `2` is indicating? Also it looks like `user` and `product` appear for the first time in this line. So, how they are linked to `userId` and `movieId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_1`, `_2`, ... `_2` are methods used to extract elements of the tuples in Scala. These have no special Spark specific context here. `user` and `product` are fields of a [`Rating`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating). And since `ratings` is `RDD[(Long, Rating)]` created as follows:

```
val ratings = sc.textFile(...).map { line =>
  ...
  (fields(3).toLong % 10, // Long
    Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toDouble)) // Rating
}
```

you should have a complete picture.

Answer (score 1):

`ratings` has type `RDD[(Int, Rating)]`. So `ratings.map` takes a function with `(Int, Rating)` argument, and `_` in `_.something` stands for this argument. `_2` returns the second field of the tuple (the `Rating`), and `user` and `product` are declared in the declaration of `Rating`.